# Image Upload with EF, MVC and JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to upload my image with the help of Jquery . But it seems I'm missing out something. In my View I've this:-

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ImageSave').click(function () {
        var Image = $("#File").val();
        var Alt = $("#Alt").val();
        var ImgGroup = $("#ImgGroup").val();
        var Year = $("#Year").val();
        var Description = $("#Description").val();

        var ImgID = {
            "Image": Image, "Alt": Alt,
            "ImgGroup": ImgGroup, "Year": Year, "Description": Description
        };
        $.post("/Admin/ImageCreate", ImgID,
        function (data) {
            if (data == "Success") {
                alert('Image Added Successfully!!');
            }
            else if (data == "Failed") {
                alert('Image Not Added!! Please Fill all Details or Contact Support')
            }

            else {
                alert(data);
            }
        }, 'json');

    });
});

@using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Image Group
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImgGroup)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImgGroup)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Year
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Year)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Year)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Description
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Image
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="File" title="Upload an image" type="file" name="file" class="btn btn-info" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Alternative Description
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Alt)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Alt)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input id="ImageSave" type="button" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

In my Controller I've two Results for GET and POST:-

```
[HttpGet]
[LogInFilter]
public PartialViewResult ImageCreate()   //Insert PartialView  
{
    return PartialView(new GarhwalBhawan.Models.ImageTbl());
}

[HttpPost]
[LogInFilter]
public JsonResult ImageCreate(GarhwalBhawan.Models.ImageTbl ImgObj, HttpPostedFileBase file) // Record Insert  
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Image/") + file.FileName);
            ImgObj.Image = file.FileName;
        }

        db.ImageTbls.Add(ImgObj);
        db.SaveChanges();
        myMessage = "Success";
    }

    else
    {
        myMessage = "Failed";
    }
    return Json(myMessage, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now when I click the Create Button. The record is saved with an anonymous path as 'C:\fakepath\22012012014.jpg' and the debugger shows that I don't have any file while saving in `file.saveas`. I can't figure out the error.

Comment: You have to use `FormData` to post files using ajax - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Comment: I'm a little lost. How to do it with Html.BeginForm(). Also I don't want to change to $.ajax can I do it with current context i.e $.post method?

Comment: What do you mean - `$.post()` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax()` - Read the answer I linked to. You need to use `FormData` and you nee to set the correct ajax options

Comment: Okay. But how will my controller map the correct HTMLcontrol in HTML to columns in model?

Comment: FGS, Did you even bother to read the link and try it!

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm sorry I'm new to ajax and mvc. I can't understand the how can I apply the solution in the link to my code.

Comment: Exactly as per the code in that answer (now a dupe) - `var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));` serializes all your form controls including the file input (exactly as explained in the dupe). Then the code in the second snippet (`$.ajax({ ...` sends to to your method and it will all be correctly bound

Comment: With reference to the linked question I changed javascript function as:-  var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ImageSave').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ImageCreate", "Admin")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formdata,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                });

            });
        });

Comment: `var formdata = ...` needs to be inside the `$('#ImageSave').click(function () {` function. And if your still having problems, then edit your question by appending the new code you have tried (or ask a new question with the relevant code) - not in comments

Comment: But my controller is getting all values as null on submit.

Comment: It certainly will if you have declared `var formdata = ...` before the `$('#ImageSave').click(function () {` And you need to learn to debug your code (but I have told you that before)

Comment: Oh Yeah!! Putting var formdata = ...  inside the $('#ImageSave').click(function () { function solved that problem. Thanks A Lot!! You have been very helpfull! A big thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract only the filename without the path from the uploaded file:

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Image/") + fileName);
```